# Merge two list on the basis of employee Alphabet (sort)

Tags: java, android

I have two list which contain header as Alphabet and the name of Employee

```
List<Item> list1 = new ArrayList<Item>();

List<Item> list2 = new ArrayList<Item>();

public List<Item> getList1() {
    list1.add("A");
    list1.add("A1");
    list1.add("A2");
    list1.add("A3");

    list1.add("B");
    list1.add("B1");
    list1.add("B2");
    list1.add("B3");

    list1.add("C");
    list1.add("C1");
    list1.add("C2");
    list1.add("C3");

    return list1;
}

public List<Item> getList2() {
    list2.add("A");
    list2.add("A4");
    list2.add("A5");
    list2.add("A6");

    list2.add("B");
    list2.add("B4");
    list2.add("B5");
    list2.add("B6");

    list2.add("C"));
    list2.add("C4");
    list2.add("C5");
    list2.add("C6");

    return list2;
}
```

I want to merge two list basis of alphabet and output should be like below

```
list1.add("A");
list1.add("A1");
list1.add("A2");
list1.add("A3");
list1.add("A4");
list1.add("A5");
list1.add("A6");


list1.add("B");
list1.add("B1");
list1.add("B2");
list1.add("B3");
list1.add("B4");
list1.add("B5");
list1.add("B6");

list1.add("C");
list1.add("C1");
list1.add("C2");
list1.add("C3");
list1.add("C4");
list1.add("C5");
list1.add("C6");
```

Please anyone let me know that How two array list will be merge according to alphabet like A,B,C etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `List` use a `Set` and when you're done merging - sort it!

```
    List<String> lst1 = getList1();
    List<String> lst2 = getList2();
    lst1.addAll(lst2);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(lst1);
    lst1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    lst1.addAll(set);
    lst1.sort(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder());
    for(String item: lst1) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
B
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
C
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
C6
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a `Set interface` and add all the data in it, that is inside of your `list1` and `list2` to eliminate **duplication** of words. And after you need to `addAll` what is inside the `set` to a new `List` and Sort it.

**sample:**

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    getList2();
    getList1();
    for(String s2 : list2)
        s.add(s2);

    for(String s2 : list1)
        s.add(s2);

    List<String> s3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    s3.addAll(s);

    Collections.sort(s3);

    for(String s2 : s3)
        System.out.println(s2);
```

**result:**

```
A
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
B
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
C
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5

C6
```